# How to combine two pivot tables into one chart in excel

Tags: excel, charts, pivot-table

I have two pivot tables, each with two columns. One column is a range from 0 to 6.5, grouped by .5 and the other column is the percentage of the whole column that the data falls into teach grouping. I need to compare these two pivot tables with an area chart that shows both areas overlapping, but I don't know how to do this.

I can make an area chart for each one individually, but I don't know how to structure the data to make the aforementioned combined chart. Here is the data:

[The Data and Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md3Bl.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go about this:

1) Insert a normal area chart (not a pivot chart) and then select the two ranges

2) The better solution is to combine both the pivot tables by combining the raw data. In this scenario you would be able to use a pivot chart.

Hope this helps.